# How to View and Edit Multiple Slides in PowerPoint (just like MS Word)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I recently got a 43" Samsung monitor for WFH. As I work with lots of Word and PowerPoint documents. For the Word, I can get as many as 6 or 8 pages at once with pretty good resolution to edit them at once. And I love it. For the PowerPoint, it only shows one slide in Normal mode. **Is there a way to show multiple slides while preparing or editing a presentation?**

I am aware of opening another instance of PowerPoint with View >> New Window. But I am looking for a single window with multiple slides, so that I can take advantage of the whole screen real estate with a ultrawide monitor.

**Note**: Check out screenshot to see what Word document look like. I have obfuscated the text. I am looking for a similar view in PowerPoint.

[image: Multiple pages of Word on a large screen]

Comment: At a basic level, you can make each slide a PP page.  You can edit the slides. Then run as slide show. Works here.

Comment: @John, can you please explain it a bit? What do you mean by making each slide a PowerPoint page? Thank you.

Comment: When I use Power Point, I make a page for each item I wish to discuss with people in an audience. Large font, one or two points per page. When done and saved, the slides can be run in a slide show.

Comment: @john, I apologize that I am still struggling to understand. How would that help with displaying multiple slides for editing which preparing for the presentation? My question is to take advantage of the huge screen real estate I have with a larger monitor, so that I can see more slides at once, (not during the slideshow, but during preparation of the slides). Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think @John's answering the same question you're asking.  The short answer to your question is "No.  PowerPoint doesn't offer anything like this capability."

Comment: Possibly not, but what I answered is how Power Point works. Possibly you are correct that Power Point does not offer the capability asked.

Comment: @John, I would have appreciated if you would have simply said, that this is not possible, rather than informing, how PowerPoint slides work at a basic level.

Comment: You can use Slide Sorter to show multiple slides, but you can not eidt them under this mode.